# FindWindow doesn't work on splashscreen

Tags: window, find, splash-screen

I need to know if a application is running its splashscreen. I can see in the taskbar and the title of the application. But FindWindow doesn't return a valid handle. But as soon as the application opens in a real window (non-splashscreen/with border) FindWindow works and return's a valid handle, the window has the exact same name.

I am using a NULL ptr for the first argument of the API. Is there any other ways to check if a process/application has opened his splashscreen? This doesn't mean check for the process itself since it takes a few seconds before the splashscreen opens.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use EnumWindows function and get all windows that belong to the specified process

```
void FindProcessWindows()
{
    DWORD pid;
    /* .. */
    /* Get target process id */
    /* .. */
    EnumWindows(&EnumWindows, pid);
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindows(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD pid;

    if((GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VISIBLE))
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
        if(pid == lParam)
        {
            /* You've found a window that belongs to the specified process */
        }
    }
}
```